# Is rank(AB) = rank(BA) if it’s known that AB and BA !=0?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Given 2 matrixes A and B:
Assuming that A and B are both nxn and that  ≠ 0 and  ≠ 0.
Does rank()=rank()?
I’ve tried like 8 different examples and they all turned out to be equal but I’m not sure whether it actually is or not, can someone help me prove/disprove this?

Comment: You can see counterexamples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77650/is-the-rank-of-ab-always-equal-to-the-rank-of-ba

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Just an explanation about why all your examples turn out to work : if you take "random" matrices, they have a high probability to be invertible. And of course, if $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then $AB$ and $BA$ *do have* the same rank. So if you want a counterexample, you must use singular matrices.